# Material Design checklist: hiding app bar on scroll?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Per the new Android Material Design checklist:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/material-design-on-android-checklist.html

> Where appropriate, upon scrolling down, the app bar can scroll off the screen, leaving more vertical space for content. Upon scrolling back up, the app bar should be shown again.

I realize there are lots of questions/answers to implement this behavior for the ICS-style app bar, but I'm curious if the new Toolbar widget or Lollipop/AppCompat 21 have introduced a more standard way of achieving this effect.

Comment: I have not seen anything in the documentation that suggests there is a built in method to hide the toolbar but since all it is, is a regular view just apply an animation to the toolbar when scrolling in either direction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Roman Nurik on Google+ (essentially what @tyczj mentioned)

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/3G8zYvN5oRC

> It's not built in but relatively simple to implement. Just observe scrolling and animate the Y translation. Could also use the "quick return" sample +Nick Butcher​ and I published a few years ago

I believe that example referenced is:
https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks

UPDATE: I also just discovered a great library that does this, along with some other great tricks https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: If using Toolbar, should it be on top of the content or next to it?

Comment: @Eric your implementationis really nice. But i have recycleView in my fragment. So i am getting confuse for how to implement the ObservableScrolView with that. Can you please update your answer or give more details for how to implement it.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I haven't tried it myself yet, but when I looked into this, I did find a github with a library you might find useful -- it looks like it should have support for `RecyclerView`  https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: @Eric thanks for reply but i have Recycler view with in that fragment. Now how to use ObservableScrollView with RecyclerView? Can you please give me any example you have?

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://material.io/develop/android/components/app-bars-bottom

hiding app bar on scroll:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    app:hideOnScroll="true"

    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_color_control_normal_24dp"
    app:navigationContentDescription="Navigation icon"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    />
```

Kotlin: programmatically

```
  bottomAppBar.hideOnScroll = true
```