# Should we replace Action Bar by ToolBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have been using `ToolBar` since it was added into **Support v7 library**. And I think I used it well. But there is a point I can't understand. Why would Google create such a widget? I mean we can do anything `ToolBar` can do by using `ActionBar`. Why do we have to use `ToolBar`? What are advantages of `ToolBar` over `ActionBar` if any? Is it necessary to replace `ActionBar` by `ToolBar`?

Any tips are appreciated. And thanks in advance.

**PS:** I found `ToolBar` is a decandant of `ViewGroup`. So, how could we use `ToolBar` like a `Layout`? Could somebody post some codes of that?

Comment: I think `quora` is better for this kind of question

Comment: For material design, yes, you should.

Comment: @BlazeTama What's `quora`?

Comment: Less than API 21, you do not have to use `ToolBar`

Comment: @Xcihnegn `ToolBar` for compatibility could be used for API 7+.

Comment: Yes I said `do not have to`, means you can use, but API>=21 you have to use ToolBar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A standard `toolbar` is for use within application content.

A `Toolbar` is a generalization of `action bar`s for use within application layouts. While an `action bar` is traditionally part of an `Activity`'s opaque `window decor` controlled by the `framework`, a `Toolbar` may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy. An application may choose to designate a `Toolbar` as the `action bar` for an `Activity` using the `setActionBar()` method.

`Toolbar` supports a more focused feature set than `ActionBar`. From start to end, a `toolbar` may contain a combination of the following optional elements:

- **A navigation button**. This may be an `Up arrow`, navigation menu toggle,
  close, collapse, done or another glyph of the app's choosing. This
  button should always be used to access other navigational
  destinations within the container of the `Toolbar` and its signified
  content or otherwise leave the current context signified by the
  `Toolbar`. The navigation button is vertically aligned within the
  `Toolbar`'s minimum height, if set.
- **A branded logo image**. This may extend to the height of the bar and
  can be arbitrarily wide.
- **A title and subtitle**. The title should be a signpost for the
  `Toolbar`'s current position in the navigation hierarchy and the
  content contained there. The `subtitle`, if present should indicate any
  extended information about the current content. If an app uses a `logo`
  `image` it should strongly consider omitting a `title` and `subtitle`.
- **One or more custom views**. The application may add arbitrary child
  views to the `Toolbar`. They will appear at this position within the
  layout. If a child view's `Toolbar`.`LayoutParams` indicates a `Gravity`
  value of `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` the view will attempt to center within the
  available space remaining in the `Toolbar` after all other elements
  have been measured.
- **An action menu**. The `menu` of actions will pin to the end of the
  `Toolbar` offering a few frequent, important or typical actions along
  with an optional `overflow menu` for additional actions. `Action` buttons
  are vertically aligned within the `Toolbar`'s minimum height, if set.

In modern `Android` UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, you should replace ActionBar with new toolbar.

Reasons

1. It looks modern and it follows new material design.
2. Unlike Action bar, toolbar is not part of window decor. You define it and place it just like any other widget... therefore, you have freedom to place it anywhere in the parent layout.
3. You have freedom to put any widget inside toolbar.
4. You can define multiple toolbars.

EDIT

What i meant is you can place other widgets (views) inside toolbar.

Create a separate layout file for the toolbar (good for reusability). In my case file name is **main_toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:App="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:segmentedgroup="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    App:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_color" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_fntsize"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_title"
        android:textColor="@color/title_text_color"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then include this toolbar in your main layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see in this example i placed TextView inside the toolbar

Comment: You say we can use `ToolBar` as a widget just like others. And after reading the doc, I find `ToolBar` inherits from `ViewGroup`,  so, do you have any successful cases of using `ToolBar` as a `Layout` just like `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`?

Answer (score 24):

> why Android would create such a widget?

Imagine, if you will, an Android tablet.

This tablet is running an app. That app has, in the lower-right corner of the screen, a rich text editor, where one can enter in some comments and format them with **bold**, *italic*, etc.

In a desktop or Web app, a typical approach for those formatting options, besides keyboard shortcuts, would be a toolbar, like the one you see above the answer text area here on Stack Overflow.

Prior to `Toolbar`, Android developers had to either roll their own toolbar, or put the formatting actions in the action bar. While the latter approach is easy, it puts a strain on the user of the aforementioned fictional app, as the user has to keep switching her visual focus from the editor (bottom of screen) to the action bar (top of screen).

> Why have we to use ToolBar?

You do not have to use `Toolbar`. I have [~300 sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus) as part of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), and at the moment, precisely zero of them use `Toolbar`. I'll have to correct that at some point, as I have not yet written a chapter on `Toolbar`.

> Is it necessary to replace ActionBar by ToolBar?

No. There is a way to do this, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Is `CommonsWare` a person or an organisation? I have read some codes of yours.

Comment: @SilentKnight: "Is CommonsWare a person or an organisation?" -- yes. :-)

Comment: I think @SilentKnight continues with the same doubt, you can be a person, an organization, or both at once, because they are the 3 possible positive answers when the operator is OR

Comment: @CommonsWare  does Toolbar suppor low level api ? i m asking for api level 7 or 8 ?

Comment: @SamirMangroliya: The version of `Toolbar` from `appcompat-v7` supports back to API Level 7.

Answer (score 17):

Toolbar is much more flexible than standard ActionBar, you can add much more tools in a Toolbar (as it extends ViewGroup), and follow Material Design Guidelines.

For example, with a Toolbar, you can do the following :

[image: My Files with big toolbar]

A regular ActionBar isn't intended to be expanded this way.

Also, you can better manipulate Toolbar content as you can include it in your Activity layout xml file. Personally, I use a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout with at the top, the Toolbar, and below, filling the leftover space, a FrameLayout where my Fragments will be added.

Finally, you can place your Toolbar anywhere you want as you set it in your layout file.

**UPDATE:**

Google released [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). The recommended way to get an extended Appbar is to wrap `Toolbar` with `AppBarLayout`, and add additional view such as `TabLayout` in. To get a FAB over the Toolbar like in this screenshot, you can use `CoordinatorLayout` to wrap your layout content, and then use anchor attributes on the FAB.

Answer (score 5):

A Toolbar is a generalization of action bars for use within application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, **a Toolbar may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy**. An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the action bar for an Activity using the setActionBar() method. You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). We replaced our actionbar, as it was easier to customize toolbar for material design. Color palettes and disappearing animation behavior for example.
Personally, I don't understand why android throws away old controls and create new one. Another example would be RecyclerView. Don't understand why they just didn't improve old API.

Comment: They've also just threw away app compat's ActionBarActivity for AppCompatActivity, so... at least they can't be faulted for inconsistency

Answer (score 5):

> Why have we to use `ToolBar`?

Toolbar is use for pre-devices and backport compatibility that the old support library does not provide. Remember `ActionbarSherlock`, android made there own to support actionbar on low level API devices.

> What are advantages of `ToolBar` over `ActionBar` if any?

You can easy add custom view with in the XML of toolbar like a relative layout view, specially a custom title and icons with animations. You have more control on your toolbar rather than the old conventional actionbar.

> Is it necessary to replace `ActionBar` by `ToolBar`?

If you are going to support actionbar on devices lower than 2.0 then yes, you need a back-port compatibility for action bar.

Answer (score 5):

1. You can easily customize toolbar.
2. You can add many widgets inside toolbar.
3. You can add many toolbar in your view.
4. You have freedom to place it anywhere in the parent layout.
5. They have own handling/managing of it child view.

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: Both will support general app navigation, icons and have backward support.

The answer depends on what user interaction(animating toolbar) your designs calls for. That being said you should implement animations on the toolbar to make it Material.

---

## ActionBar:

If you simply want a static bar at the top that can host icons, back button and you can theme.

## Toolbar:

If you want to do anything beyond a static bar such as animations.

A common implementation and Google design recommendation is to hide the toolbar when scrolling.
[Material Design checklist: hiding app bar on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616427/material-design-checklist-hiding-app-bar-on-scroll/26662419#26662419)

Comment: The thing is that you don't have too many options when you want to theme old ActionBar. Let's say you want to make ActionBar with some gradient background, showing picture other than App icon on it's left side. It is possible but good luck implementing some clean solution. With toolbar this or any even more exotic customization is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

The support `Toolbar` gives you so much more flexibility and freedom, at practically no added extra cost, that there's no reason I can think of not to make the transition. Transitioning to the new `Toolbar` is actually one of the first steps to porting existing apps to a more Material design, due to the simplicity of the task, and the immediate effect it has on the overall look and feel of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation link -- http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Note that it doesn't include the code where you include it in your other layout files:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>
```

Why I changed to Toolbar -- One of the reasons I changed a recent app to Toolbar was that when we wanted to customise the action bar, it wouldn't work on different Android versions or when we extended certain classes (making it transparent or showing an icon instead of the app name). Toolbars have allowed us the customisation options we want.